# Categorical and ordinal variables and one dependent discrete variable

Tags: categorical-data, causality, ordinal-data

Í have a dataset with two categorical variables: let's say "city type" (categorical) and "living crampedness" (ordinal), and one discrete dependent variable ("house square meterage"). I'm supposed to analyze whether the two independent variables explain or have a relationship to the dependent variable. Any tips on how to go about this?

Comment: You describe the outcome as continuous in the title and discrete in the text. Discrete or continuous outcome, a good place to start is plotting your data.

Comment: @dipetkov it's discrete! i messed up the title, sorry

Comment: Please edit title and text of question to show what you're asking. Not eveyone reads Comments.